# Tax fraud, revealed on the show

Tags: united-states, tax-law

A person on disability, supposedly can only make $1000/month without having to report that income to the IRS. If a person on the show is shown to make more than they should, revealed in a case before Judge Judy, does she report this to the IRS?

Comment: Does who report 'this' to the IRS? The claimant?  Judge Judy?

Answer (score 2):

Neither "Judge Judy", nor anyone connected with the show, is to the best of my understanding **required** to make such a report to the IRS, or to any other government agency. But neither are they forbidden from making a report should one of them choose to do so. For the matter of that, you, or anyone who saw the show, could make a report.

I did not see this particular show, and I don't know how clear it was that the person was in violation. It might be that some exception applies.

Also, news reports say that the IRS is currently underfunded and overworked. A disabled person making a bit over $1000 per month probably does not owe a large tax bill, even if in violation. Such a case might well not be a priority for the IRS.

Oh by the way, failure to report income is not "tax fraud", that is making false or misleading reports, and I think there is also an intent requirement. "Failure to file" is illegal, but under a different provision.

Comment: There was a case in the UK, where a woman claiming benefits appeared on the "Big Brother" show, was paid £30,000, and the people handling her benefits watched the show.

Comment: @gnasher729 https://www.lep.co.uk/whats-on/arts-and-entertainment/woman-who-claimed-housing-benefit-while-living-big-brother-house-ordered-pay-it-all-back-107099